# How do I access the information from QLineEdit widget from another class?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

PYQT5 ON PYCHARM

Currently, I have a MainWindow(mainwindow.py) class and a DialogWindow(dialog.py) class. Also, I have a main.py file which runs the code for both classes. I would like to set the text of the label in dialog.py to be the information from mainwindow.py, QLineEdit, inputedit. May I know how will I be able to do this? Appreciate any help provided. Thanks!

mainwindow.py

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.inputedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inputedit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 80, 311, 21))
        self.inputedit.setPlaceholderText("Input company name in ALL CAPITAL LETTERS")
        self.inputedit.setObjectName("inputedit")
```

dialog.py

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 351, 91))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "ASD"))
```

main.py

```
class MyDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui  = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    def dialogbox(self):
        self.hide()
        self.myDialog = MyDialog()
        self.myDialog.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to access both objects in a scope that share that in this case it is dialogbox, considering the above the solution is:

```
def dialogbox(self):
    self.hide()
    self.myDialog = MyDialog()
    self.myDialog.ui.label.setText(self.ui.inputedit.text())
    self.myDialog.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It needed a minor tweak to self.myDialog.ui.label.setText(self.ui.inputedit.text()).

Comment: @AngYangCheng I missed the "ui", I fixed it. The main part of my answer is not the code but the explanation as it will help you in other cases.